# pyqtgraph grabFrameBuffer saves an empty image

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I have a 3D rendering that looks like the image below that I am trying to save. The image however comes out black with nothing drawn and I am not sure why. I am following the guide here https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exporting.html#exporting-3d-graphics which does not provide a lot of help. It just writes `glview.grabFrameBuffer().save('fileName.png')`

[image]

Here are the important parts of the code. I replaced the section rendering out the lines and point clouds with a single line render.

```
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl

from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # initialize screen
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = gl.GLViewWidget()
    
    line = np.array([[0,0,0],[1,1,1]])
    line_renderer = gl.GLLinePlotItem(pos=line, width=1, antialias=False)
    w.addItem(line_renderer)
    
    g = gl.GLGridItem()
    w.addItem(g)
    w.show()
    w.grabFrameBuffer().save('fileName.png')
    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grabFrameBuffer()` creates a QImage based on what is shown in the `GLViewWidget`, but the rendering of the instructions is not instantaneous but you have to wait for Qt to do it. Considering the above, the solution is to use a QTimer to do this task a moment later:

```py
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(100, lambda: w.grabFrameBuffer().save("fileName.png"))
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to increase the time in order to render out my scene with the lines and point clouds as I was still getting an empty image with 100ms. Is there a way to automatically determine the length or force qt to save only after the rendering is done? Or must I trial and error several values?

Comment: @Kong In general, it should be higher than the refresh time, which is generally 30ms, so set 100ms to have an image. On the other hand I think that in its real application it requires a longer time for other reasons that I do not know since you do not provide an MRE of that code so I will not point out anything else for it: It cannot indicate anything about a code that I do not know